# disable call from mac ring

Tags: iphone, ipad, mac, wifi-calling

I don't know if this is the correct way to describe this or not... so here goes:

a) I have an iPHONE, a MAC + Tablet.

b) It is important that I keep my mac + tablet - attached with my apple id for other reasons.

c) I also really like the fact I can answer my cellphone via my MAC or TABLET

d) HOWEVER ... most often I leave my MAC + TABLET at home, and take my cellphone with me - when I am away from home - my MAC rings, and my TABLET rings - rather loudly according to "she who must be obeyed"

Why: Because my tablet & laptop are often plugged in charging.-

This is also bad - because when I get a "SPAM CALL" - my iPhone very nicely routes it to voice mail, but ... my Tablet and MAC ring at ear-breaking decible levels.

According to "she who must be obeyed" violence upon my MAC + TABLET may occur if I cann't fix this.

e) BUT - I do not want to LOGOUT of iCLOUD ... for other reasons above -- My question is this:  I need some way to mute the ringing, or control the volume when I am not home.  Or possibly turn this on - when I am actively using the computer, ie: with when locked - disable this.

Comment: Why are you shouting?  (CAPS = shout). Which Mac specifically?  What version of macOS? Which iPhone and version of iOS?  Same question for your “tablet” which I presume is an iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to Settings on your phone and then go to Phone, there is an option that reads 'Calls on other devices'. You can turn that off when you leave and the other devices should not ring. Only your iPhone. It will list other devices on your network and you can turn off the ones you choose.

Comment: For good measure, you might need to check this on iPad as well. If the ipad is receiving calls from Messages/iCloud - the phone may not necessarily be the device that hands off incoming calls.

Comment: I found the setting on my phone - I'll try that when I get home.

Comment: JUST CONFIRMING - This works great. All settings are controlable from your phone, the menu sequence is: SETTINGS -> PHONE -> Calls on Other Devices -> Select The Devices.